# FFmpeg Unknown input format: 'gdigrab'

Tags: ffmpeg, ubuntu-18.04, video-capture, screen-recording

Basically I am using ubuntu 18.04 and I am trying to get a specific window screen and record it into the .flv or .mp4 file using **FFmpeg** but when I run this command

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i title="german.avi - VLC media player" -b:v 3M  germ.flv
```

I got an error attached in the screenshot
Saying **Unknown input format: 'gdigrab'**

[image]

I tried to use **dshow** instead of **gdigrab** but got same error.
Can someone tell me how to solve this issue or another method that could be able to record a specific window screen.

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

`gdigrab` and `dshow` are only meant for Windows.

On linux, use `x11grab`. See `-ffmpeg -h demuxer=x11grab` for options.

Comment: can you tell me how can I change this command for x11grab so I could be able to get a specific screen recording?

Comment: @Abdulahad have you tried `ffmpeg -f x11grab -framerate 30 -i title=Calculator output.mkv`? Please, change "title" for the window.

Answer (score -1):

Install the new version of FFMPEG.

https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html

Comment: I have updated to new version of FFmpeg but that doesn't work for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).